# Tcl-C program crashes in Tcl_CreateObjCommand

Tags: api, crash, tcl

I got the following crash when I used my package I provided in some shell of tcl.
My package works good on every tcl shell that is running 64bit version , but when I am using this shell it crushes (the crush is when I am using my Tcl_C Api and the functions I created with it).

This is the backtrace of gdb debugger:

```
--- Stack trace follows:
at /u/my_user/workspace/user_prog/user_dev/tb/xtg_agent/xtg_agentpkg.sv, 15
Dumping VCS Annotated Stack:                                                     
#0  0x00002aaab50b286d in waitpid () from /lib64/libc.so.6                       
#1  0x00002aaab5044479 in do_system () from /lib64/libc.so.6                     
#2  0x00002aaab50447b0 in system () from /lib64/libc.so.6                        
#3  0x00002aaaae421dab in le_10ee25eff68cd8461c9146fa1d0b35e87067f3c8015b313e639d2928478c79b3f673f99203bcf8be64600612100082236bffb2007f1e0ef9 () from /global/apps/vcsmx_2017.03-SP2-7-Z/linux64/lib/liberrorinf.so                                                                                                   
#4  0x00002aaaae4237b6 in le_10ee25eff68cd8461c9146fa1d0b35e87067f3c8015b313efba706aab251478fa49e66610e453774633a6c152e7ef778f2202cda681f3d4e () from /global/apps/vcsmx_2017.03-SP2-7-Z/linux64/lib/liberrorinf.so                                                                                                   
#5  0x00002aaaae41c885 in le_d35ca1ff70d465c2b9b1a72eee90a506fdd009d3de3db1de () from /global/apps/vcsmx_2017.03-SP2-7-Z/linux64/lib/liberrorinf.so      
#6  0x00002aaab0c23458 in le_64133461705005bb725549e2e6fa1b3f () from /global/apps/vcsmx_2017.03-SP2-7-Z/linux64/lib/libvcsnew.so                        
#7  0x00002aaab0a84bee in le_82244d58c54c18c70d63edc9becab634 () from /global/apps/vcsmx_2017.03-SP2-7-Z/linux64/lib/libvcsnew.so                        
#9  0x00002aaab5038495 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6                                                                                                     
#10 0x00002aaab5039c75 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6                                                                                                     
#11 0x00002aaaaed93a7d in Tcl_PanicVA () from /u/my_user/workspace/user_prog/user_dev/utils/tcl8.6.6/lib/libtcl8.6.so                                  
#12 0x00002aaaaed93b3d in Tcl_Panic () from /u/my_user/workspace/user_prog/user_dev/utils/tcl8.6.6/lib/libtcl8.6.so                                    
#13 0x00002aaaaedaf227 in Ptr2Block () from /u/my_user/workspace/user_prog/user_dev/utils/tcl8.6.6/lib/libtcl8.6.so                                    
#14 0x00002aaaaedaf80b in TclpFree () from /u/my_user/workspace/user_prog/user_dev/utils/tcl8.6.6/lib/libtcl8.6.so                                     
#15 0x00002aaaaeccba9c in Tcl_DeleteCommandFromToken () from /u/my_user/workspace/user_prog/user_dev/utils/tcl8.6.6/lib/libtcl8.6.so                   
#16 0x00002aaaaeccc12d in Tcl_CreateObjCommand () from /u/my_user/workspace/user_prog/user_dev/utils/tcl8.6.6/lib/libtcl8.6.so                         
#17 0x00002aaacf446f31 in Tclprogapi_Init (interp=0x8f5410) at /u/my_user/workspace/user_prog/user_dev/uapi/PROG_TCL.cpp:67   
...
```

there are additional lines but they just tracing to another files that are not related to the TCL_C API or to the system files.

I am thinking it has something to do with the shared object of the API that this shell has (maybe some old version that not support Objects).

Comment: The crash is inside the deleting of an existing command (so that your new commands can replace it) and looks like it is probably caused by some sort of memory corruption. Somewhere. Memory corruption bugs aren't the easiest to hunt. Can you do a build with a tool like electricfence or purify?

Comment: You are going to need to look at your custom object source code and find the ref count incr/decr bug that is causing the bad memory ref.